# I want to make a log in page using mysqli and i get this error "Cannot pass parameter 1 by reference"

Tags: php, mysqli

And this is my code:

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM `my___passloging` WHERE `puser` = ? AND `ppass` = ?";       
$procces = $this->db->prepare($q); 
$procces->bind_result("ss", $user, $pass);
```

Comment: Read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php there's something you're not doing.

Comment: [Don't limit passwords](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)  and [use the proper methods to hash passwords with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html).

Answer (score 1):

You never executed your query.

```
$procces = $this->db->prepare($q); 

$procces->execute(); // this part

$procces->bind_result("ss", $user, $pass);
```

Example from the manual:

```
/* prepare statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT Code, Name FROM Country ORDER BY Name LIMIT 5")) {
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind variables to prepared statement */
    $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2);
```

- Unless you want to `bind_param()` instead of using `bind_result()`, to which you still need to execute that statement.

Example from the manual:

```
/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT District FROM City WHERE Name=?")) {

    /* bind parameters for markers */
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $city);

    /* execute query */
    $stmt->execute();

    /* bind result variables */
    $stmt->bind_result($district);
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.